# MOCK data in MySQL data base for php application

Tags: php, mysql, testing

i've developed a online portal with php/mysql. Now i need to test it but i need to create mock user profiles inorder to check the full functionality and optimize mysql query.

I need about 1000 user profiles. it would take alot of time to do manually to fill name, dob, address, phone number etc. is there any way to create mock up data easily. or is there any application that would create these data for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use [this online data generator](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of one item data and iterate over user creation process

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Benerator](http://databene.org/databene-benerator).

It is a very powerful tool to create test (dummy) data for a database.

It does have a learning curve though.